# PHP SoapClient - SOAP request with long integer

Tags: php, soap, long-integer, soap-client

I have some troubles with large integer values and PHP SoapClient class. It seems that SoapClient cannot handle large numeric values - and I can't send a number larger than PHP_INT_MAX (2147483647), even though the SOAP parameter type is "xsd:long".

This is the WSDL specification of the SOAP method I need to call:

```
<message name="doFinishItemRequest">
  <part name="session-handle" type="xsd:string"/>
  <part name="finish-item-id" type="xsd:long"/>
  <part name="finish-cancel-all-bids" type="xsd:int"/>
  <part name="finish-cancel-reason" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>
```

The value of `finish-item-id` is `"3599569593`" (a string loaded from MySQL BIG INT type). But it seems that SoapClient is casting it to 32-bit integer.

The SOAP envelope looks like this:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:AllegroWebApi" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:doFinishItem>
      <session-handle xsi:type="xsd:string">8a5d261806a4b60a283dabdb092e061a2d46e5d80bcc68bb00_56</session-handle>
      <finish-item-id xsi:type="xsd:long">2147483647</finish-item-id>
      <finish-cancel-all-bids xsi:type="xsd:int">0</finish-cancel-all-bids>
      <finish-cancel-reason xsi:type="xsd:string"></finish-cancel-reason>
    </ns1:doFinishItem>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

It changed 3599569593 to 2147483647 and the SOAP service is telling me that I'm passing wrong ID.

Is there a workaround? (I can't change the WSDL.)

Answer (score 3):

You haven't shown any PHP code, but casting to float seems to work.

```
$soapVar = (float)'3599569593';
```

Or when you send it as parameter.

Comment: PHP Soap extensions used to only support 32 bit ints even on 64 bit systems.  That's probably still the case.